# while using MOD in oracle sql, i am getting error

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my code-
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4qlD.png)

error-
number or types of arguments are calling =

i think it's a syntax error. i am getting same error in most of my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong syntax.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comparisonlike (g IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5     RETURN CASE WHEN MOD (g, 2) = 0 THEN 'EVEN' ELSE 'ODD' END;
  6  END;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> select comparisonlike(25) result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
ODD

SQL> select comparisonlike(12) result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
EVEN

SQL>
```

---

If you want to check digit *anchored* to the end of the string, then

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comparisonlike (g IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5     RETURN CASE WHEN MOD (TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(g, '\d$')), 2) = 0 THEN 'EVEN'
  6                 ELSE 'ODD'
  7            END;
  8  END;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT comparisonlike(22) res_1,                    --> 22 is being checked
  2         comparisonlike('1st great result13') res_2   --> 13 is being checked
  3  FROM dual;

RES_1      RES_2
---------- ----------
EVEN       ODD

SQL>
```

Comment: what if our input is 'great1' or 'great2', then how do we check odd even

Comment: These are strings and - from my point of view - aren't odd nor even. How would you check it? By the last character? What if string was 'my 1st though 12'? Is it odd or even? Perhaps you should restrict the IN parameter's datatype to NUMBER (instead of VARCHAR2).

Comment: YES i want to check it from last character like "1st great result1" or "great 2 result1". i want a code to check if the input is odd or even. i want all in 1 function. the above code and this case. both in 1 func.

Comment: OK; I edited the answer and added option which handles that. Have a look, please.